# Parsing html/text return type to be able to see the content with AFNetworking

Tags: json, swift, post, afnetworking

I am constrained to using AFNetworking, but I am working in Swift. I am trying to retrieve data from a POST API request that is supposed to be returning JSON. However it seems that no matter how I make the request I am not able to see what is being returned and that it does not seem to be in proper JSON format. Here's what I've tried.

(1) The canonical approach:

```
manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer.init(readingOptions: .AllowFragments)
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes  = serialiazationTypes
```

This produces the error: **Invalid value around character 2**

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 2., NSUnderlyingError=0x60800004ad70 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000a2c140> { URL: https://API_ADDRESS} { status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 2261;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 07 Dec 2016 15:46:26 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.10.1";
} },
```

(2) Using the standard parser. So basically I removed any explicit setting of the response serializer, which produced this error:

```
Optional(Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000004ace0 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x61800082e6a0> { URL: https://API_ADDRESS } { status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 2261;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 07 Dec 2016 15:49:12 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.10.1";
```

(3) So then I tried to read as text/html, not requiring JSON, so that I could see what the problem is, but I don't seem to be able to retrieve this and just see what the content is either. So with this code:

`manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()`

I ended up with this response, which does not even indicate why this is a bad request:

```
 "Request failed: bad request (400)" 
{ status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 2261;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 07 Dec 2016 15:51:10 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.10.1";
} }
```

Here are my questions

(1) In cases 1 & 2 above are these problems with parsing the response code whereas in case 3 I am just seeing the server tell me that my request is bad?

(2) How can I start figuring out why my request is bad? This is an internal API, but I'm not getting a lot of help with how it works. I have a sample `curl` command that does work with the API, but I'm not clear on how I am departing from it:

```
curl -X POST -v -s -H "Session-Token: EYYW$YW$YWYW" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d@sample.json https://API_ADDRESS
```

What is different between that and what I am doing below:

```
manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()

manager.requestSerializer.setValue(sessionToken, forHTTPHeaderField: tokenString)
manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")

manager.POST(
                user_url,
                parameters: nil,
                success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?,
                    responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                    print("JSON FROM POST: \(responseObject)")
                },
                failure:  { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?, error: NSError?) in
                    print("there was an error in POST: \(error)")
                }
            )
```